# Error: error getting broadcast client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline

Tags: go, kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-chaincode

I have been trying to install external chaincode. I have two different chaincode which are question and response. When I try to make a request to install them to orderer endpoint, orderee throws TLS handshake error. Here are logs from terminal:

```
approval for question chaincode for govt
2021-07-12 11:46:33.416 UTC [chaincodeCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Retrieved channel (commonchannel) orderer endpoint: orderer:7050
Error: error getting broadcast client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode question has been successfully defined on channel commonchannel and try again: chaincode question not found" 
packaging chaincode question in general org
packaging chaincode question
Installing chaincode question on peer0.govt...
+ peer lifecycle chaincode install question.tgz
+ res=0
2021-07-12 11:46:37.747 UTC [cli.lifecycle.chaincode] submitInstallProposal -> INFO 001 Installed remotely: response:<status:200 payload:"\nMquestion_1.0:46d1bcf1da31e07857befec181044f864e8c62b4b6680fe7c1c462c549d8f16e\022\014question_1.0" > 
2021-07-12 11:46:37.747 UTC [cli.lifecycle.chaincode] submitInstallProposal -> INFO 002 Chaincode code package identifier: question_1.0:46d1bcf1da31e07857befec181044f864e8c62b4b6680fe7c1c462c549d8f16e
```

Similar for other chaincode and with different peers.

Here are logs from orderer:

```
2021-07-12 11:46:10.578 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> INFO 028 Start accepting requests as Raft leader at block [0] channel=commonchannel node=1
2021-07-12 11:46:19.020 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 029 Error reading from 172.17.0.1:31028: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2021-07-12 11:46:19.020 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 02a streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.17.0.1:31028 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=7.012539ms
2021-07-12 11:46:19.328 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] propose -> INFO 02b Created block [1], there are 0 blocks in flight channel=commonchannel node=1
2021-07-12 11:46:19.328 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> INFO 02c Received config transaction, pause accepting transaction till it is committed channel=commonchannel node=1
2021-07-12 11:46:19.330 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN 02d Error reading from 172.17.0.1:9223: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2021-07-12 11:46:19.330 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 02e streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=172.17.0.1:9223 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=14.828989ms
2021-07-12 11:46:19.397 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] writeBlock -> INFO 02f Writing block [1] (Raft index: 3) to ledger channel=commonchannel node=1
2021-07-12 11:46:22.893 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 030 Error reading from 172.17.0.1:23084: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2021-07-12 11:46:22.893 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 031 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.17.0.1:23084 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=8.869097ms
2021-07-12 11:46:23.217 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] propose -> INFO 032 Created block [2], there are 0 blocks in flight channel=commonchannel node=1
2021-07-12 11:46:23.218 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> INFO 033 Received config transaction, pause accepting transaction till it is committed channel=commonchannel node=1
2021-07-12 11:46:23.220 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN 034 Error reading from 172.17.0.1:29447: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2021-07-12 11:46:23.220 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 035 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=172.17.0.1:29447 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=11.339499ms
2021-07-12 11:46:23.288 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] writeBlock -> INFO 036 Writing block [2] (Raft index: 4) to ledger channel=commonchannel node=1
2021-07-12 11:46:33.418 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 037 Server TLS handshake failed in 12.482µs with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.17.0.1:55689
2021-07-12 11:46:34.420 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 038 Server TLS handshake failed in 602.493µs with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.17.0.1:21589
2021-07-12 11:46:36.321 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 039 Server TLS handshake failed in 54.319µs with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.17.0.1:24287
2021-07-12 11:46:47.531 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 03a Server TLS handshake failed in 9.79µs with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.17.0.1:49121
2021-07-12 11:46:48.536 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 03b Server TLS handshake failed in 32.343µs with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.17.0.1:6624
2021-07-12 11:46:50.362 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 03c Server TLS handshake failed in 22.315µs with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.17.0.1:16789
2021-07-12 11:47:00.954 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 03d Server TLS handshake failed in 2.001672ms with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.17.0.1:64657
2021-07-12 11:47:01.955 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 03e Server TLS handshake failed in 18.907µs with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.17.0.1:46802
2021-07-12 11:47:03.449 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 03f Server TLS handshake failed in 96.18µs with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.17.0.1:19547
2021-07-12 11:47:14.573 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 040 Server TLS handshake failed in 13.576µs with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.17.0.1:7268
2021-07-12 11:47:15.576 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 041 Server TLS handshake failed in 929.686µs with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.17.0.1:18461
2021-07-12 11:47:17.309 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 042 Server TLS handshake failed in 18.362µs with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.17.0.1:13545
```

Someone please help me fix this. I have tried everything I could.

Comment: is your orderer running with TLS enabled or not?

Comment: @yacovm yes, TLS is enabled for approving the orgs but chaincode installation is without TLS